# jquery autocomplete using json

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have tried so many things but I don't understand this sooo confusing.

I have this

```
<input id="wba" type="search" name="q" value="" class="search box" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" class="search button" />
```

also 
a php file

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$arr = array('test'=>'hello world');

echo json_encode($arr);
```

as for javascript I have tried everything including the demos from the jquery website but no luck ... someone out there help me setup the autocomplete to display the data?

**EDIT**

```
$(function() {
        function log(message) {
            $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
            $("#log").attr("scrollTop", 0);
        }

        $("#wba").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "search.php",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.sites, function(item) {
                            alert(item);
                            window.console.debug(item);
                            return {

                                label: item.name ,
                                value: item.url
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                log(ui.item ? ("Selected: " + ui.item.name) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
    });
```

This code is from the jqueryui website (demo) ...

Comment: Can you post an example of the javascript you were trying to use? There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
// JS
$(function() {
  $("#wba").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { q: request.term },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(value,key) {
            return { label:value.label , value: value.val }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2
  });
});​

// PHP
$results = array(
   array('label' =>'label1', 'val' => 'value1'),
   array('label' =>'label2', 'val' => 'value2'),
   array('label' =>'label3', 'val' => 'value3')
);
// Optionally do something with the user input ($_GET["input_value"])
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($result).');'​​​​​​​​​
```

i dont know why but this does work...

Comment: it doesn't work... it returns the jason data but there is nothing dropping down

Comment: updated code, i can give you the example link if you want but it should work... fingers crossed

Comment: thnx man the only problem there is that it expects at lest two characters before it fires

Comment: until u remembered the minLength

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise, without any code, is this:

- In jQuery, bind an event listener to the input so that when the user types something, a function is called
- That function then sends the value of the input to your php script using one of jQuery's ajax functions
- The php script echos a json encoded string
- The jquery ajax function receives the string
- That function then takes the json data and appends it in some stylized way to the outside of the input
- Each of those options has an event listener bound so that when an option is clicked, something happens - either the input is filled with the clicked item, another function is run, a page is loaded, etc.

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this, which is why I didn't answer with an actual function. It depends on your goals.

Comment: I think the poster is asking how to feed JSON into the [jQuery UI autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) :)

Comment: I didn't ask for the process I am familiar with that... i just can't get the returned data to go to the drop down or log or however ppl like to call it :)

Comment: @Nick ah. Missed that :) @Val My bad on the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented it using C# on the server.

**JavaScript**

```
function InitializeElement (element) {
    element.autocomplete("ServerPage.ashx", {
        formatItem: function(data) {
            return "<span style=\"font-size:9pt;word-break:break-all;\">" + data[0] + "<br />" + data[1] + "</span>";
        }
    });
    element.result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        jq(event.currentTarget).siblings('input[type=hidden]').val(data[2]);
        event.currentTarget.value = data[0];
        event.currentTarget.title = data[1];
    });
}
```

**C#**

```
public class ServerPage : ApplicationHandler 
{ 
    protected override void Process()
    {
        String text = (this.Request.Params["q"] ?? String.Empty);

        if (text.Length > 0)
        {
            using (DatabaseRecords records = this.Core.Database.ExecuteRecords("StoredProcedure", new KeyValue("Text", text)))
            {
                while (records.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write(records.GetString("Code") + "|" + records.GetString("Description") + "|" + records.GetInt32("Id") + "\n");   
                }   
            }
        }       
    }
}
```